# Why would IndexOf be unavailable in my array? I'm targeting .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a straight forward string array, why would IndexOf be unavailable? I'm targeting .Net 3.5

Thanks

Comment: show compilation error please :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about the [Array.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof.aspx) method:

```
var array = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(array, "b"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you are assuming it is an instance method instead of a static method:

```
using System;

class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    string[] arr = new string[] { "hello", "world" };
    int index = Array.IndexOf(arr, "world");
    // Not:
    //int index = arr.IndexOf("world");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(index == 1);
  }
}
```

Consider `List<string>` instead of an array, List<>.IndexOf() is an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you thought you could apply IndexOf as though it were an instance method is that some for types an extension method wraps Array.IndexOf() as Microsoft has for the GeoCoordinate class.

The following will work on *all* arrays:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
  public static int IndexOf(this object[] oa, object o)
  {
    return Array.IndexOf(oa, o);
  }
}
```

And here's a snippet of code showing how the code becomes more legible - at the price of making it dependent on the extension method class. I've deliberately undone the syntactic sugar on one of them so you can side-by-side compare.

```
  int m = Array.IndexOf(II, closestItems[0]);
  int n = II.IndexOf(closestItems[1]);
```