# How do I find the position of an element in a C# array

Tags: c#

I have a C# array of integers. The integers in the array are all unique. For example the array contains page numbers: 1,2,4,5,7,9

If I am on page 5 I would like to have a previous button to take me to page 4 and 8.

My question is how can I find the index position in an array if I just know it's the row that contains the number "5"?

Hope someone can help.

thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would IndexOf be unavailable in my array? I'm targeting .Net 3.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349402/why-would-indexof-be-unavailable-in-my-array-im-targeting-net-3-5)

Answer (score 6):

[Array.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat.aspx) method:

```
var array = new[] { 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9 };
var index = Array.IndexOf(array, 5);
```

Comment: Just beware with non-primitive types: you better have IComparable/IEquatable implemented or you'll end up with unexpected results

Comment: @Darin - `I'm using Array.IndexOf()` to dig through the `args[]` values in a console app. Do you know of a faster way to do this? To replace: `var i = Array.IndexOf(args, "-f");`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following code should work:

```
static int IndexOf(int[] arr, int input)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
        if (arr[i] == input) return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Edit: I didn't know that that method already exists